# How to run a mapreduce job from JSP or PHP page hosted on a server?

Tags: java, php, hadoop, mapreduce, jobs

I have hadoop 1.0.4 installed on ubuntu 11.04 , I want someone to be able to submit an input on which my predefined map-reduce will work and create an output file somewhere on my system through a webpage that takes input, I know only two server side languages and I hope it's possible through either one of the two.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. In java, don't perform the job in the jsp. Look into servlets.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis any readable/tutorial that you would recommend?

Comment: Sure, for any tag on SO, you can use the search function as, example `[servlets]` and look at the `info` tab. For `servlets`, that would be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) page. For `jsp`, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)